# Rails - best_in_place jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, best-in-place

Okay, I'm really pulling my hair out here! I'm using the gem [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place). But I always have a conflict with jQuery and I don't know what the problem is.

> Uncaught TypeError: Property `'$'` of object `[object DOMWindow]` is not a function

I can confirm that jQuery is first loaded and best_in_place.js second.

**|| SOLUTION ||**

But not the right solution.

Convert every $-sign to 'jQuery'

Comment: Looking at `best_in_place`, it's very poorly written, and it's likely its fault that you're getting this error. It doesn't follow any of the conventions for writing a jQuery plugin at all.

Comment: Yup, true story, but converted every $-sign to 'jQuery'. Now every-things works. I'll it for the moment, but isn't the right solution

Comment: In fairness to `best_in_place`, it's not supposed to be a jQuery plugin; it's a set of Rails helpers.